# Will view update automatically based on latest date captured in source table?

Tags: sql, view

let's say I have table A storing records with a date column in values of July 2020, Aug 2020 and Sep 2020
I create view B to capture columns from table A and only include latest date records

eg.

```
create view B as
select * from A
where A.date = (select max(date)
                from A);
```

if next month my table A also include date with values of Oct2020, then will view B automatically include only records Oct2020 instead of Sept2020 next time?

Answer (score 0):

Views do not *update* (well, let's keep materialized views out of this).

A standard view is a query that is substituted into another query when you reference it.  Nothing is stored, so nothing is "updated".  But, when you query the view, you always see the latest data in the underlying tables.

If you wanted to "freeze" the data, you would create a table instead of a view.